# SQL Order by from another table

Tags: php, sql, sql-order-by

I'm trying to display my posts by upvote on my page.

My table **posts**:

```
(id, post_name, post_description, post_category, post_subcategory)
```

and table **votes**:

```
(id, post_id, vote_rank)
```

I can display all my post with

```
$bdd->query('SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_subcategory = "'.$_GET['s'].'" ORDER BY post_name');
```

I tried with JOIN but nothing appears.

```
$bdd->query('SELECT *
            FROM posts AS p
               JOIN votes as v ON v.post_id = p.id
            WHERE p.post_subcategory =  "'.$_GET['s'].'" 
            ORDER BY v.vote_rank');
```

Any idea?

Comment: Please do not compose queries with concats: use parameters such that the content is escaped.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$bdd->query('SELECT p.*
        FROM posts p LEFT JOIN votes v ON v.post_id = p.id
        WHERE p.post_subcategory =  "'.$_GET['c'].'" 
        ORDER BY v.vote_rank');
```

Try It

Answer (score 0):

Try using the inner join

```
$bdd->query('SELECT p.*
        FROM posts p inner join votes v on v.post_id = p.id
        where p.post_subcategory =  "'.$_GET['c'].'" 
        order by v.vote_rank');
```

Comment: Doesn't work with `inner join` but works with `left join`